Import std header unit in module implementation file
I'm running on VS2022 17.10.1 (latest) with MSVC and C++20:
This is my module iface - hello.iface.ixx :
export module hello;

export void hi();

And this is its impl - hello.impl.cpp:
module hello;
import <iostream>;

void hi() {
    std::cout << "hi";
}

It does not compile due to this line:
import <iostream>;

There are a few ways to solve it but I'm unsure which one is proper.

If I change hello.impl.cpp file to .ixx or Compile As: /interface it works.
It looks like header unit import is only accepted in an interface file. What are the implications? two BMI's are created? I read that I better stick with .cpp files for module implementation files.

If I add the import <iostream>; to  hello.iface.ixx it works.
But it seems to me like bad practice to reveal that I'm using  on iface. As only impl uses cout.

I can use global module fragment in hello.impl.cpp. But I think the #include <iostream> might be less efficient than the supported import <iostream>; in the two options above.


I will mention that it works as is with Preview /std:c++latest

In project's properties -> C++ -> scan source for Module Dependencies: Yes.

That works! Thank you!
An interesting observation is that if another module interface file imports the same header an import, if the same header would work. Perhaps also imports of other headers as well, that is if perphas such import changes the " scan source for Module Dependencies" property.
